# Dropping row in pandas by index - have to add to index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of 182 rows that comes from read_csv. The first column, sys_code, contains various alphanumeric codes. I want to drop ones that start with 'FB' (there are 14 of these). I loop through the dataframe, adding what I assume would be the index to a list, then try to drop by index using the list. But this doesn't work unless I add 18 to each index number.

Without adding 18, I get a list containing numbers from 84 - 97. When I try to drop the rows using this list for indexes, I get KeyError: '[84] not found in axis'. But when I add 18 to each number, it works fine, at least for this particular dataset. But why is this? Shouldn't i be the same as the index number?

```
fb = []
i = 0
df.reset_index(drop=True)
for x in df['sys_code']:
    if x[:2] == 'FB':
        fb.append(i+18)    #works
        fb.append(i)       # doesn't work
    i += 1
df.drop(fb, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Series.str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html). Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['some string', 'FBsomething', 'FB', 'etc']})
print(df)

     col1
0  some string
1  FBsomething
2           FB
3          etc
```

You could remove those strings that do not start with `FB` using:

```
df[~df.col1.str.startswith('FB')]

      col1
0  some string
3          etc
```

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of that syntax with the ~ symbol. I had to modify the code a bit - `df = df[~df.col1.str.startswith('FB')]`, but works great. Still don't know why original code gave error though.